# Combobox: Change items name, keep value

Tags: c#, combobox

is it possible to change the name of a combobox-item without changing the actual value? I´m currently displaying some IDs in my combobox, but I want to display a "placeholder" name rather than the actual value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change `Text` property of checkbox, without change `Value` property.
(CheckBox have lot of properties : Name, Text, Value , ....), but you can't change `Name` property of CheckBox.

```
YouCheckBox.Text = "set your new text, this text will be print in your screen, but it's not your value and it's not your name";
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are asking about System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.

MSDN documentation for ComboBox.Item property states that:
Although the ComboBox is typically used to display text items, you can add any object to the ComboBox. Typically, the representation of an object in the ComboBox is the string returned by that object's ToString method. If you want to have a member of the object displayed instead, choose the member that will be displayed by setting the DisplayMember property to the name of the appropriate member. You can also choose a member of the object that will represent the value returned by the object by setting the ValueMember property.

You could add custom objects with ID and DisplayName properties to the combobox and just override the ToString() method to return the DisplayName.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Combo box.item.text = xyz;<br>
Combo box.item.value = zyx;
```